# OpenFlow with XML Object

Tags: iphone, coverflow

Trying to use OpenFlow API for iPhone SDK.
I need the openflow to load pictures from a (image) link.

This is how it always works with local images:

```
    loadImagesOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];


    NSString *imageName;
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", i];
        [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forIndex:i];
        [imageName release];
        NSLog(@"%d is the index",i);

    }
    [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:10];
```

And I tried this:

```
    - (void)openFlowView:(AFOpenFlowView *)openFlowView requestImageForIndex:(int)index {

    NSString *photoUrl = [[oldEntries objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"still"];
    NSURL *photomake = [NSURL URLWithString:photoUrl];
    NSLog(@"theConnection: %@",photoUrl);
    NSLog(@"theConnection: %@",photomake);

    AFGetImageOperation *getImageOperation = [AFGetImageOperation alloc];
    // We're getting our images from the Flickr API.
    getImageOperation.imageURL = photomake;

    [loadImagesOperationQueue addOperation:getImageOperation];

    [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:1];
    [getImageOperation release];
}
```

But it just won't work.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what 'won't work' it's hard to say, please clarify and supply the actual URL you are creating.

The only line that looks suspect is this one:

```
AFGetImageOperation *getImageOperation = [AFGetImageOperation alloc];
```

Should be:

```
AFGetImageOperation *getImageOperation = [[AFGetImageOperation alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use:

```
NSURL *imageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[@"path/to/the/file.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

put all the images in an Array
and then you call you first function

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", i];
    [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:**image** forIndex:i];
    [imageName release];
    NSLog(@"%d is the index",i);

}
[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:10];
```